# Как правильно написать запрос посредством библиотеки pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет!

У меня есть рабочий код на python, но мне он не нравиться из-за громозкости. 
Как с помощью библиотеки pandas и groupby сделать данный код более локаничным? Пока только начал изучать эту библиотеку и не совсем разобрался с ее потенциалом.

```
    openHigh07 = 0
    openHigh10 = 0 
    openHigh15 = 0
    openLow07 = 0
    openLow10 = 0
    openLow15 = 0 

    for item in ohlcv.values:
        koh = item[2]/item[1]
        if(koh >= 1.007): openHigh07 = openHigh07 + 1
        if(koh >= 1.01): openHigh10 = openHigh10 + 1
        if(koh >= 1.015): openHigh15 = openHigh15 + 1

        kol = item[1]/item[3]
        if(kol >= 1.007): openLow07 = openLow07 + 1
        if(kol >= 1.01): openLow10 = openLow10 + 1
        if(kol >= 1.015): openLow15 = openLow15 + 1
```

Результат

```
openHigh07 = 20
openHigh10 = 13
openHigh15 = 5
openLow07 = 21
openLow10 = 19
openLow15 = 3
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой (3-5 строк) воспроизводимый пример данных и результирующий набор данных - то что вы хотите получить на выходе. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Не совсем понял причем здесь Pandas - Pandas предназначен для работы с матричными или векторными данными. У вас в вопросе 6 скаляров...

Comment: Думал может с помощью groupby count можно как-то красивее подсчитать.

Comment: Может и можно, но как «натянуть» скаляры на DataFrame. В общем пример данных в вашем вопросе не соотносится с Pandas